# Remove matching string in array

Tags: ruby

```
 array=["dog","cat","monkey","cat","bear"]
```

I tried this:

```
    array.uniq
    ["dog", "cat", "monkey", "bear"]
```

I also tried

```
 array.inject{|memo,word| word==memo}
```

but that did not work either. I'm stumped.

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution:
 Find dupes, then delete words in the array that are in the dupes array

```
dupes=array.group_by {|e| e}.map { |e| e[0] if e[1][1]}.compact

array.delete_if{|word| dupes.include?(word)}
```

Comment: Grab duplicates

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to remove all elements of `array` that appear more than once? If so, say that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wish to remove all elements of array that appear more than once.

```
array - array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }.
              select { |_,v| v > 1 }.
              keys
  #=> ["dog", "monkey", "bear"]
```

The steps are as follows.

```
g = array.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |s,h| h[s] += 1 }
  #=> {"dog"=>1, "cat"=>2, "monkey"=>1, "bear"=>1} 
h = g.select { |_,v| v > 1 }
  #=> {"cat"=>2} 
a = h.keys
  #=> ["cat"] 
array - a
  #=> ["dog", "monkey", "bear"]
```

Comment: Cary for the win! I love it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
array=["dog","cat","monkey","cat","bear"]

puts array.reject { |e| array.count(e)>1 }

# dog
# monkey
# bear
```

It runs in `O(n²)`, so don't use it for your DNA research, but for smallish number of elements it should be fine.

To make it faster, use a prepared hash table:

```
array=["dog","cat","monkey","cat","bear"]

count = {}
array.each { |e| count[e] = (count[e]||0) + 1 }

puts array.reject { |e| count[e]>1 }

# dog
# monkey
# bear
```

I do not know what kind of implementation `Hash` uses, so can't give a true complexity, but I would expect it be somewhere between `O(n)` and `O(n*logn)`.

Slight variation just for fun:

```
array=["dog","cat","monkey","cat","bear"]

count = {}
array.each { |e| count[e] = (count[e]||0) + 1 }

count.delete_if { |key, value| value>1 }

puts count.keys

# dog
# monkey
# bear
```

Comment: Using `count` for each element of an array of size n is relatively inefficient: O(n^2). You're better off getting the counts first, using an O(n) method. One of the latter is to use a counting hash, as I did in my answer; another is to use the method [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by).

Comment: @CarySwoveland, thanks for your comment, if you read my answer you will see that I gave 3 possible ways to solve this, including complexity; two of which use a pre-hashed result.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't read your entire answer, which is quite a good one.  In general, rather than saying, "Here's solution #1. Here's solution #2, which is better than solution #1", consider saying nothing about #1. Showing inferior solutions just weakens your answers (imo). You can of course chain what you have: `array.each_with_object({}) { |e,count| count[e] = (count[e]||0) + 1 }.delete_if { |key, value| value>1 }.keys`, which is perhaps worth mentioning.

Comment: I see what you mean, @CarySwoveland, and you are right in a way, certainly. In fact, I intentionally did it this way because in plenty of cases, where there truly are only a few values, having a very short and succinct solution (a one-liner, or half-liner like here) can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `delete_if` to remove an item matching a string:

```
array=["dog","cat","monkey","cat","bear"]
array.delete_if{|item| item == 'dog'}
=> ["cat", "monkey", "cat", "bear"]
```

You can also use the simpler `delete`:

```
array.delete('cat')
=> ["monkey", "bear"]
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if

Comment: That won't work if I have an unknown array of strings.

Comment: Clarify your question, and then I'll update the answer.